# What do I lose by not creating an EA account?

Tags: ps-vita, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

Since I'm a lone wolf and I don't like playing online, I have zero interest in creating an EA account. However, the game tells me that by doing that some content will be locked. What exactly is this locked content? Is it just the online part (understandable) or there are some offline bits locked as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole campaign would still be playable.
(Basically any race or events that only have you; the player and NPC/AIs in it)

EDIT: Or split-screen co-op.

When it said:

> Some content will be locked

It means that anything require internet access (or online authentication), for example (but not limited to):

- Unlocks requiring online play (ie. Win X races)
- Multiplayer (ie. Races, Challenges etc.)
- DLC Activation?
- ... and social features.